# Error using corrplot : incorrect graphical type 'u'

Tags: r, shiny, correlation, r-corrplot

I have got the weirdest problem using the `corrplot()` function.
I was trying to use it in a ShinyDashboard first, but I realized that even when putting the code alone, I get the same error.
Here is the simple code:

```
library(corrplot)
mcor <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(mcor, type="upper", order="hclust", tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : type de graphe incorrect 'u'
```

The type is supposed to be "upper", "lower" or "full", so I don't know why this error occurs.
When I erase the argument type="upper" I do get a correlation circle, but what I want to have is a heatmap of the correlations.
Could you help me understand what is going wrong ?

EDIT:

Well it seems that when rebooting everything and running the code, it works.

But if I try to do it after or inside my shinydashboard, the error occurs.
I'm really stuck with this one, I updated all my packages and rebooted several times but it didn't solve the problem.

Has anyone ever try to put a correlation heatmap in a shiny app ?I'm now wondering if shiny isn't refusing this type of graphic.

Hereunder is my simplified shiny dashboard:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(HistData)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(png)
library(pid)
library(corrplot)
library(pls)
library(plsdepot)
library(corrplot)
TrameTest <- read.table("C:/Users/AUB/Desktop/Gaz 
Industriels/Resultats finalV2.csv", 
                    sep=";",dec=",", header= TRUE)
list_variables <- colnames(TrameTest)[9:46]

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Gaz Industriels"
              )             
  ,
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("InterpretationPEX", tabName = "InterpretationPEX", icon = 
icon("bar-chart"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
     #PEX tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "InterpretationPEX",
              h2("Plan d'Expérience"),
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Matrice des corrélations", status = "primary",
                    plotOutput("plot44", height = 600)
                )
              )  
      )


    )
  ))
#####server
server<-function(input, output){ 
vars <-c("THC_inC", "Abattement_C", "TIT11", "L_G")
corTest <- cbind(TrameTest[,"THC_inC"], TrameTest[,"Abattement_C"], 
TrameTest[,"TIT11"], TrameTest[,"L_G"])
colnames(corTest)<- vars
corTest2 <-cor(corTest, method="pearson", use = "complete.obs")
output$plot44<-renderPlot({
  corrplot (corTest2, type="upper", order="AOE",tl.col="black", tl.cex=1, 
tl.srt=35, addCoef.col="black")
}) 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Your code works fine for me. Have you tried starting a fresh session and rerunning?

Comment: your code works well for me

Comment: Code works fine for `R.3.4.1`. Please add your `sessionInfo()`. Also, post is tagged with *shiny*, maybe add more context?

Comment: I edited my post with the code I use to make a shiny dashboard. I'm now wondering if corrplot is compatible with shiny ?

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue has to do with `corrplot` being a command in the `corrplot` package and pls.  If you type

```
corrplot::corrplot (corTest2, type="upper", order="AOE",tl.col="black", tl.cex=1, tl.srt=35, addCoef.col="black")
```

it should work.